# Jira REST call not working on staging, OK on prod

Tags: rest, jira

So, when providing the following REST call to our prod instance of Jira, it works fine:

```
curl -D- -u XXXXX:XXXX -X POST --data '{"fields":{"project":{"key":"TOOL"},"summary":"sum sommery","description":"my description","issuetype":{"name":"Incident - No Impact"},"priority":{"name":"Minor"}}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -k https://hostname.net/rest/api/latest/issue/
```

But on staging, the same call (cut-and-pasted, except hostname.staging.net) returns the error message:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Tue, 10 Jun 2014 19:18:54 GMT
Server: Apache
X-AREQUESTID: 918x72821x1
X-ASEN: SEN-L3544367
X-Seraph-LoginReason: OK
X-ASESSIONID: 1fytmp3
X-AUSERNAME: nicholsp
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, no-transform
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=7FA0FEE96594E7AB6AF29AD6A124DF4F; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: atlassian.xsrf.token=BD5E-7MMA-4RXJ-SU24|0f63cd883e32a1a1eda451fe11ca3925e58a5140|lin; Path=/
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"issuetype":"issue type is required"}}
```

It looks like we're including the issue type to me....

Answer (score 0):

Something is not the same on staging. Take a fresh snapshot of the database from your live environment and try again.